# How to print mmap file content ? void * to char *

Tags: c

```
int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
struct stat bf;
fstat(fd, &bf);
void *adr = mmap(NULL, bf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
for (size_t i = 0; i <= bf.st_size; i++)
{
    printf("%c", adr[i]); // doesn't work invalid use of void expression
}
```

I'm trying to print the content a file, but I don't understand why I can't convert
to char*

```
printf("%c", (char*) adr[i]);
```

Comment: You need: `((char*)adr)[i]`.

Comment: You could assign the returned address by `mmap` to a `char *`. This will automatically work and the compiler won't complain. So you could consider declaring `char *adr`. It prevents quite some annoying type casts.